# Websocketapps to add another query when the argument value is changed

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, websocket, python-multithreading

Maybe I am not sure how to ask this question correctly because I was not able to find a good answer from googling on my own.

I am pretty close, but I have one last step to complete the script below. The script is using YLiveTicker to pull real-time stock data from webstream of finance.yahoo.com for a given list of stock symbols from a csv file ('stock_selection_active.csv'). The list will look like this: ['NLSPW', 'ENTX', 'TRCH', 'NVFY']. The modified YLiveTicker script then takes the list and listen to the webstream for the given symbols. But the problem is that I have to terminate the script and re-run it if the list of stock symbols is updated. I want to modify the script where it automatically does this.

For example, I can initially have ['NLSPW', 'ENTX', 'TRCH', 'NVFY'], and once 'AAPL' is added as another item in the list, it will add an additional query of 'AAPL' to the websocket.

I guess I am struggling to manipulate websocketapp. I was kinda able to replicate some parts of the script with websockets and asyncio libraries to set up a server and a client to interact for a similar effect, but it only pulls empty data from wss://streamer.finance.yahoo.com.

How can I modify the scripts below to constantly check for the csv file and add another symbol to the websocketapp for querying?

```
import base64
import json, sys, os, csv
import websocket
import asyncio
#import websockets
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import pandas as pd
from pytz import timezone
from pathlib import Path
from yaticker_pb2 import yaticker

try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread

nyc = timezone('America/New_York')
today_str = datetime.today().astimezone(nyc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
PATH = Path(__file__).parent
DATA_PATH = PATH.joinpath("data").resolve()
DATE_DATA_PATH = DATA_PATH.joinpath(today_str)

if not os.path.exists(DATE_DATA_PATH):
    os.makedirs(DATE_DATA_PATH)

stock_selection = DATA_PATH.joinpath("stock_select_active.csv")

def PullTickersToQuery():
    if os.path.exists(stock_selection):
        df = pd.read_csv(stock_selection)
        tickers_to_query = df['Symbol'].tolist()
        return (tickers_to_query)

class YLiveTicker:
    def __init__(
        self,
        on_ticker=None,
        ticker_names=['MSFT'],
        on_error=None,
        on_close=None,
        enable_socket_trace=False,
    ):

        self.symbol_list = dict()
        self.symbol_list["subscribe"] = ticker_names

        websocket.enableTrace(enable_socket_trace)

        self.on_ticker = on_ticker
        self.on_custom_close = on_close
        self.on_custom_error = on_error

        self.yaticker = yaticker()

        self.ticker_names = ticker_names
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
            "wss://streamer.finance.yahoo.com/",
            on_message=self.on_message,
            on_error=self.on_error,
            on_close=self.on_close,
        )
        self.ws.on_open = self.on_open
        self.ws.run_forever()

    def on_message(self, message):
        message_bytes = base64.b64decode(message)
        self.yaticker.ParseFromString(message_bytes)
        data = {
            "Symbol": self.yaticker.id,
            "Exchange": self.yaticker.exchange,
            "QuoteType": self.yaticker.quoteType,
            "Price": self.yaticker.price,
            "Timestamp": (datetime.today().astimezone(timezone('America/New_York')).strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f')), #self.yaticker.time,
            "MarketHours": self.yaticker.marketHours,
            "ChangePercent": self.yaticker.changePercent,
            "DayVolume": self.yaticker.dayVolume,
            "DayHigh": self.yaticker.dayHigh,
            "DayLow": self.yaticker.dayLow,
            "Change": self.yaticker.change,
            "PriceHint": self.yaticker.priceHint,
            'Bid': self.yaticker.bid,
            'BidSize': self.yaticker.bidSize,
            'Ask': self.yaticker.ask,
            'AskSize': self.yaticker.askSize
        }

        quoteType = {
            0: 'NONE',
            5: 'ALTSYMBOL',
            7: 'HEARTBEAT',
            8: 'EQUITY',
            9: 'INDEX',
            11: 'MUTUALFUND',
            12: 'MONEYMARKET',
            13: 'OPTION',
            14: 'CURRENCY',
            15: 'WARRANT',
            17: 'BOND',
            18: 'FUTURE',
            20: 'ETF',
            23: 'COMMODITY',
            28: 'ECNQUOTE',
            41: 'CRYPTOCURRENCY',
            42: 'INDICATOR',
            1000: 'INDUSTRY',
        }

        marketHoursType = {
            0: 'PRE_MARKET',
            1: 'REGULAR_MARKET',
            2: 'POST_MARKET',
            3: 'EXTENDED_HOURS_MARKET'
        }


        for q in quoteType:
            if data['QuoteType'] == q:
                data['QuoteType'] = quoteType[q]

        for m in marketHoursType:
            if data['MarketHours'] == m:
                data['MarketHours'] = marketHoursType[m]

        row = list(data.values())
        headers = list(data.keys())
        print (row)

        STOCK_DATA_PATH = DATE_DATA_PATH.joinpath('{}.csv'.format(data['Symbol']))
        file_exists = os.path.isfile(STOCK_DATA_PATH)

        with open(STOCK_DATA_PATH, 'a') as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', fieldnames=headers)
            
            if not file_exists:
                writer.writeheader()

            writer.writerow(data)
            f.close()

    def on_error(self, error):
        if self.on_custom_error is None:
            print(error)
        else:
            self.on_custom_error(error)

    def on_close(self):

        if self.on_custom_close is None:
            #print("### connection is closed ###")
            pass
        else:
            self.on_custom_close()

    def on_open(self):
        def run(*args):
            #self.symbol_list = PullTickersToQuery()
            #print (self.symbol_list)
            self.ws.send(json.dumps(self.symbol_list))

        thread.start_new_thread(run, ())
        #print("### connection is open ###")
        print('Symbol,Exchange,MarketHours,QuoteType,Date,Price,ChangePercent,DayVolume,DayHigh,DayLow,Bid,BidSize,Ask,AskSize')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tickers_to_query = PullTickersToQuery()
    YLiveTicker(ticker_names=tickers_to_query)
```

yaticker_pb2.py

```
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: yaticker.proto

import sys
_b=sys.version_info[0]<3 and (lambda x:x) or (lambda x:x.encode('latin1'))
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import message as _message
from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
from google.protobuf import descriptor_pb2
# @@protoc_insertion_point(imports)

_sym_db = _symbol_database.Default()




DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor.FileDescriptor(
  name='yaticker.proto',
  package='',
  syntax='proto3',
  serialized_pb=_b('\n\x0eyaticker.proto\"\xcb\x08\n\x08yaticker\x12\n\n\x02id\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\r\n\x05price\x18\x02 \x01(\x02\x12\x0c\n\x04time\x18\x03 \x01(\x12\x12\x10\n\x08\x63urrency\x18\x04 \x01(\t\x12\x10\n\x08\x65xchange\x18\x05 \x01(\t\x12&\n\tquoteType\x18\x06 \x01(\x0e\x32\x13.yaticker.QuoteType\x12.\n\x0bmarketHours\x18\x07 \x01(\x0e\x32\x19.yaticker.MarketHoursType\x12\x15\n\rchangePercent\x18\x08 \x01(\x02\x12\x11\n\tdayVolume\x18\t \x01(\x12\x12\x0f\n\x07\x64\x61yHigh\x18\n \x01(\x02\x12\x0e\n\x06\x64\x61yLow\x18\x0b \x01(\x02\x12\x0e\n\x06\x63hange\x18\x0c \x01(\x02\x12\x11\n\tshortName\x18\r \x01(\t\x12\x12\n\nexpireDate\x18\x0e \x01(\x12\x12\x11\n\topenPrice\x18\x0f \x01(\x02\x12\x15\n\rpreviousClose\x18\x10 \x01(\x02\x12\x13\n\x0bstrikePrice\x18\x11 \x01(\x02\x12\x18\n\x10underlyingSymbol\x18\x12 \x01(\t\x12\x14\n\x0copenInterest\x18\x13 \x01(\x12\x12)\n\x0boptionsType\x18\x14 \x01(\x0e\x32\x14.yaticker.OptionType\x12\x12\n\nminiOption\x18\x15 \x01(\x12\x12\x10\n\x08lastSize\x18\x16 \x01(\x12\x12\x0b\n\x03\x62id\x18\x17 \x01(\x02\x12\x0f\n\x07\x62idSize\x18\x18 \x01(\x12\x12\x0b\n\x03\x61sk\x18\x19 \x01(\x02\x12\x0f\n\x07\x61skSize\x18\x1a \x01(\x12\x12\x11\n\tpriceHint\x18\x1b \x01(\x12\x12\x10\n\x08vol_24hr\x18\x1c \x01(\x12\x12\x18\n\x10volAllCurrencies\x18\x1d \x01(\x12\x12\x14\n\x0c\x66romcurrency\x18\x1e \x01(\t\x12\x12\n\nlastMarket\x18\x1f \x01(\t\x12\x19\n\x11\x63irculatingSupply\x18  \x01(\x01\x12\x11\n\tmarketcap\x18! \x01(\x01\"\x80\x02\n\tQuoteType\x12\x08\n\x04NONE\x10\x00\x12\r\n\tALTSYMBOL\x10\x05\x12\r\n\tHEARTBEAT\x10\x07\x12\n\n\x06\x45QUITY\x10\x08\x12\t\n\x05INDEX\x10\t\x12\x0e\n\nMUTUALFUND\x10\x0b\x12\x0f\n\x0bMONEYMARKET\x10\x0c\x12\n\n\x06OPTION\x10\r\x12\x0c\n\x08\x43URRENCY\x10\x0e\x12\x0b\n\x07WARRANT\x10\x0f\x12\x08\n\x04\x42OND\x10\x11\x12\n\n\x06\x46UTURE\x10\x12\x12\x07\n\x03\x45TF\x10\x14\x12\r\n\tCOMMODITY\x10\x17\x12\x0c\n\x08\x45\x43NQUOTE\x10\x1c\x12\x12\n\x0e\x43RYPTOCURRENCY\x10)\x12\r\n\tINDICATOR\x10*\x12\r\n\x08INDUSTRY\x10\xe8\x07\"\x1f\n\nOptionType\x12\x08\n\x04\x43\x41LL\x10\x00\x12\x07\n\x03PUT\x10\x01\"a\n\x0fMarketHoursType\x12\x0e\n\nPRE_MARKET\x10\x00\x12\x12\n\x0eREGULAR_MARKET\x10\x01\x12\x0f\n\x0bPOST_MARKET\x10\x02\x12\x19\n\x15\x45XTENDED_HOURS_MARKET\x10\x03\x62\x06proto3')
)



_YATICKER_QUOTETYPE = _descriptor.EnumDescriptor(
  name='QuoteType',
  full_name='yaticker.QuoteType',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  values=[
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='NONE', index=0, number=0,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='ALTSYMBOL', index=1, number=5,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='HEARTBEAT', index=2, number=7,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='EQUITY', index=3, number=8,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='INDEX', index=4, number=9,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='MUTUALFUND', index=5, number=11,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='MONEYMARKET', index=6, number=12,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='OPTION', index=7, number=13,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='CURRENCY', index=8, number=14,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='WARRANT', index=9, number=15,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='BOND', index=10, number=17,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='FUTURE', index=11, number=18,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='ETF', index=12, number=20,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='COMMODITY', index=13, number=23,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='ECNQUOTE', index=14, number=28,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='CRYPTOCURRENCY', index=15, number=41,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='INDICATOR', index=16, number=42,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='INDUSTRY', index=17, number=1000,
      options=None,
      type=None),
  ],
  containing_type=None,
  options=None,
  serialized_start=730,
  serialized_end=986,
)
_sym_db.RegisterEnumDescriptor(_YATICKER_QUOTETYPE)

_YATICKER_OPTIONTYPE = _descriptor.EnumDescriptor(
  name='OptionType',
  full_name='yaticker.OptionType',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  values=[
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='CALL', index=0, number=0,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='PUT', index=1, number=1,
      options=None,
      type=None),
  ],
  containing_type=None,
  options=None,
  serialized_start=988,
  serialized_end=1019,
)
_sym_db.RegisterEnumDescriptor(_YATICKER_OPTIONTYPE)

_YATICKER_MARKETHOURSTYPE = _descriptor.EnumDescriptor(
  name='MarketHoursType',
  full_name='yaticker.MarketHoursType',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  values=[
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='PRE_MARKET', index=0, number=0,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='REGULAR_MARKET', index=1, number=1,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='POST_MARKET', index=2, number=2,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='EXTENDED_HOURS_MARKET', index=3, number=3,
      options=None,
      type=None),
  ],
  containing_type=None,
  options=None,
  serialized_start=1021,
  serialized_end=1118,
)
_sym_db.RegisterEnumDescriptor(_YATICKER_MARKETHOURSTYPE)


_YATICKER = _descriptor.Descriptor(
  name='yaticker',
  full_name='yaticker',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  containing_type=None,
  fields=[
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='id', full_name='yaticker.id', index=0,
      number=1, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=_b("").decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='price', full_name='yaticker.price', index=1,
      number=2, type=2, cpp_type=6, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=float(0),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='time', full_name='yaticker.time', index=2,
      number=3, type=18, cpp_type=2, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='currency', full_name='yaticker.currency', index=3,
      number=4, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=_b("").decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='exchange', full_name='yaticker.exchange', index=4,
      number=5, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=_b("").decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='quoteType', full_name='yaticker.quoteType', index=5,
      number=6, type=14, cpp_type=8, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='marketHours', full_name='yaticker.marketHours', index=6,
      number=7, type=14, cpp_type=8, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='changePercent', full_name='yaticker.changePercent', index=7,
      number=8, type=2, cpp_type=6, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=float(0),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='dayVolume', full_name='yaticker.dayVolume', index=8,
      number=9, type=18, cpp_type=2, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='dayHigh', full_name='yaticker.dayHigh', index=9,
      number=10, type=2, cpp_type=6, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=float(0),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='dayLow', full_name='yaticker.dayLow', index=10,
      number=11, type=2, cpp_type=6, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=float(0),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='change', full_name='yaticker.change', index=11,
      number=12, type=2, cpp_type=6, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=float(0),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='shortName', full_name='yaticker.shortName', index=12,
      number=13, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=_b("").decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='expireDate', full_name='yaticker.expireDate', index=13,
      number=14, type=18, cpp_type=2, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='openPrice', full_name='yaticker.openPrice', index=14,
      number=15, type=2, cpp_type=6, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=float(0),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='previousClose', full_name='yaticker.previousClose', index=15,
      number=16, type=2, cpp_type=6, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=float(0),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='strikePrice', full_name='yaticker.strikePrice', index=16,
      number=17, type=2, cpp_type=6, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=float(0),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='underlyingSymbol', full_name='yaticker.underlyingSymbol', index=17,
      number=18, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=_b("").decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='openInterest', full_name='yaticker.openInterest', index=18,
      number=19, type=18, cpp_type=2, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='optionsType', full_name='yaticker.optionsType', index=19,
      number=20, type=14, cpp_type=8, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='miniOption', full_name='yaticker.miniOption', index=20,
      number=21, type=18, cpp_type=2, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='lastSize', full_name='yaticker.lastSize', index=21,
      number=22, type=18, cpp_type=2, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='bid', full_name='yaticker.bid', index=22,
      number=23, type=2, cpp_type=6, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=float(0),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='bidSize', full_name='yaticker.bidSize', index=23,
      number=24, type=18, cpp_type=2, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='ask', full_name='yaticker.ask', index=24,
      number=25, type=2, cpp_type=6, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=float(0),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='askSize', full_name='yaticker.askSize', index=25,
      number=26, type=18, cpp_type=2, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='priceHint', full_name='yaticker.priceHint', index=26,
      number=27, type=18, cpp_type=2, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='vol_24hr', full_name='yaticker.vol_24hr', index=27,
      number=28, type=18, cpp_type=2, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='volAllCurrencies', full_name='yaticker.volAllCurrencies', index=28,
      number=29, type=18, cpp_type=2, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='fromcurrency', full_name='yaticker.fromcurrency', index=29,
      number=30, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=_b("").decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='lastMarket', full_name='yaticker.lastMarket', index=30,
      number=31, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=_b("").decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='circulatingSupply', full_name='yaticker.circulatingSupply', index=31,
      number=32, type=1, cpp_type=5, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=float(0),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='marketcap', full_name='yaticker.marketcap', index=32,
      number=33, type=1, cpp_type=5, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=float(0),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
  ],
  extensions=[
  ],
  nested_types=[],
  enum_types=[
    _YATICKER_QUOTETYPE,
    _YATICKER_OPTIONTYPE,
    _YATICKER_MARKETHOURSTYPE,
  ],
  options=None,
  is_extendable=False,
  syntax='proto3',
  extension_ranges=[],
  oneofs=[
  ],
  serialized_start=19,
  serialized_end=1118,
)

_YATICKER.fields_by_name['quoteType'].enum_type = _YATICKER_QUOTETYPE
_YATICKER.fields_by_name['marketHours'].enum_type = _YATICKER_MARKETHOURSTYPE
_YATICKER.fields_by_name['optionsType'].enum_type = _YATICKER_OPTIONTYPE
_YATICKER_QUOTETYPE.containing_type = _YATICKER
_YATICKER_OPTIONTYPE.containing_type = _YATICKER
_YATICKER_MARKETHOURSTYPE.containing_type = _YATICKER
DESCRIPTOR.message_types_by_name['yaticker'] = _YATICKER
_sym_db.RegisterFileDescriptor(DESCRIPTOR)

yaticker = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('yaticker', (_message.Message,), dict(
  DESCRIPTOR = _YATICKER,
  __module__ = 'yaticker_pb2'
  # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:yaticker)
  ))
_sym_db.RegisterMessage(yaticker)


# @@protoc_insertion_point(module_scope)
```

Comment: As I am looking for same thing, I came across same question: how to add more or change the list. I have no experience with python. My suggestion would be to create tickerlist.json file and use python to read the file and use it's content (list of tickers). Another service will listen for file change and restart this main stript to give it a chance to reload new tickers. What u think?

Comment: I finally solved the problem. The problem was that I thought that I had to somehow modify the websocket portion of the script. The solution was to modify the thread portion. I will go ahead and upload the solution in a min.

Comment: @Maka, That may be one of the ways that we can tackle this problem, but I simply decided to pull the list from csv file. It is completely up to you, but I used the thread function to pull the updated list every 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. As noted in the comments section, I had to modify the thread function to run in intervals.

As you can see below, we are sending jsonified dictionary in the run function. And then, I created a separate function called 'every', so that I can call that function inside of the 'thread.start_new_thread' in order to run it every 15 seconds. In this way, the function is running the part of the script every set interval.

```
 def on_open(self):
        def run(*args):
            self.ws.send(json.dumps(CreateTickersDict()))

        thread.start_new_thread(lambda: every(15, run), ())
        print('Symbol,Exchange,MarketHours,QuoteType,Date,Price,ChangePercent,DayVolume,DayHigh,DayLow,Bid,BidSize,Ask,AskSize')
```

And here is the full script:

```
import base64
import json, sys, os, csv
import websocket
import asyncio
#import websockets
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time, traceback
import pandas as pd
from pytz import timezone
from pathlib import Path
from yaticker_pb2 import yaticker
import logging
try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread


nyc = timezone('America/New_York')
today_str = datetime.today().astimezone(nyc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
PATH = Path(__file__).parent
DATA_PATH = PATH.joinpath("data").resolve()

DATE_DATA_PATH = DATA_PATH.joinpath(today_str)
#DATE_DATA_PATH = DATA_PATH.joinpath('2021-03-15')
if not os.path.exists(DATE_DATA_PATH):
    os.makedirs(DATE_DATA_PATH)

stock_selection = DATA_PATH.joinpath("stock_select_active.csv")

def every(delay, task):
    next_time = time.time() + delay
    while True:
        time.sleep(max(0, next_time - time.time()))
        try:
            task()
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()
            # in production code you might want to have this instead of course:
            # logger.exception("Problem while executing repetitive task.")

        # skip tasks if we are behind schedule:
        next_time += (time.time() - next_time) // delay * delay + delay

def PullTickersList():
    if os.path.exists(stock_selection):
        df = pd.read_csv(stock_selection)
        tickers_to_query = df['Symbol'].tolist()
        return (tickers_to_query)

def CreateTickersDict():    
    symbol_list = dict()
    symbol_list["subscribe"] = PullTickersList()
    #print (symbol_list)
    return (symbol_list)


class YLiveTicker:
    def __init__(
        self,
        on_ticker=None,
        ticker_names=['MSFT'],
        on_error=None,
        on_close=None,
        enable_socket_trace=False,
    ):
        #ticker_names = PullTickersList()
        #print (ticker_names)
        #self.symbol_list = dict()
        self.symbol_list = CreateTickersDict

        websocket.enableTrace(enable_socket_trace)

        self.on_ticker = on_ticker
        self.on_custom_close = on_close
        self.on_custom_error = on_error

        self.yaticker = yaticker()

        self.ticker_names = ticker_names
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
            "wss://streamer.finance.yahoo.com/",
            on_message=self.on_message,
            on_error=self.on_error,
            on_close=self.on_close,
        )
        self.ws.on_open = self.on_open
        self.ws.run_forever()

    def on_message(self, message):
        message_bytes = base64.b64decode(message)
        self.yaticker.ParseFromString(message_bytes)
        data = {
            "Symbol": self.yaticker.id,
            "Exchange": self.yaticker.exchange,
            "QuoteType": self.yaticker.quoteType,
            "Price": self.yaticker.price,
            "Timestamp": (datetime.today().astimezone(timezone('America/New_York')).strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f')), #self.yaticker.time,
            "MarketHours": self.yaticker.marketHours,
            "ChangePercent": self.yaticker.changePercent,
            "DayVolume": self.yaticker.dayVolume,
            "DayHigh": self.yaticker.dayHigh,
            "DayLow": self.yaticker.dayLow,
            "Change": self.yaticker.change,
            "PriceHint": self.yaticker.priceHint,
            'Bid': self.yaticker.bid,
            'BidSize': self.yaticker.bidSize,
            'Ask': self.yaticker.ask,
            'AskSize': self.yaticker.askSize
        }

        quoteType = {
            0: 'NONE',
            5: 'ALTSYMBOL',
            7: 'HEARTBEAT',
            8: 'EQUITY',
            9: 'INDEX',
            11: 'MUTUALFUND',
            12: 'MONEYMARKET',
            13: 'OPTION',
            14: 'CURRENCY',
            15: 'WARRANT',
            17: 'BOND',
            18: 'FUTURE',
            20: 'ETF',
            23: 'COMMODITY',
            28: 'ECNQUOTE',
            41: 'CRYPTOCURRENCY',
            42: 'INDICATOR',
            1000: 'INDUSTRY',
        }

        marketHoursType = {
            0: 'PRE_MARKET',
            1: 'REGULAR_MARKET',
            2: 'POST_MARKET',
            3: 'EXTENDED_HOURS_MARKET'
        }


        for q in quoteType:
            if data['QuoteType'] == q:
                data['QuoteType'] = quoteType[q]

        for m in marketHoursType:
            if data['MarketHours'] == m:
                data['MarketHours'] = marketHoursType[m]

        row = list(data.values())
        headers = list(data.keys())
        print (row)

        STOCK_DATA_PATH = DATE_DATA_PATH.joinpath('{}.csv'.format(data['Symbol']))
        file_exists = os.path.isfile(STOCK_DATA_PATH)

        with open(STOCK_DATA_PATH, 'a') as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', fieldnames=headers)
            
            if not file_exists:
                writer.writeheader()

            writer.writerow(data)
            f.close()

    def on_error(self, error):
        if self.on_custom_error is None:
            print(error)
        else:
            self.on_custom_error(error)

    def on_close(self):

        if self.on_custom_close is None:
            #print("### connection is closed ###")
            pass
        else:
            self.on_custom_close()

    def on_open(self):
        def run(*args):
            self.ws.send(json.dumps(CreateTickersDict()))

        thread.start_new_thread(lambda: every(15, run), ())
        print('Symbol,Exchange,MarketHours,QuoteType,Date,Price,ChangePercent,DayVolume,DayHigh,DayLow,Bid,BidSize,Ask,AskSize')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    YLiveTicker()
```

Note that the user no longer has to specify the list as a part of the argument of YLiveTikcer() as I already created separate functions to pull the updated list every 15 seconds now.